# Jquery file upload, images not showing up without refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I've been trying to implement jquery file upload into my current application for the past week now. I've followed Ryan's jquery file upload video and almost everything works as expected. The only issue I am having is that whenever I upload files they do not appear on the page unless I refresh the page.

my photos.js.coffee looks like this

> $ ->
>
> $("#new_photo").fileupload
>
> dataType: "script"

my create.js.erb looks like this

> ```
> <% if @photo.new_record? %>
> ```
>
> alert("Failed to upload photo: <%= j @photo.errors.full_messages.join(', ').html_safe %>");
>
> ```
> <% else %>
> ```
>
> $("#photos").append("<%= j render(@photo) %>");
>
> ```
> <% end %>
> ```

I've tried switching append with html and the result doesn't change. If you need any other code please let me know.

Comment: If they are being saved with the same filename it is likely because they are being cached by the browser. Try adding a timestamp or ID to the name.

Comment: I'm certain $("#photos").append("<%= j render(@photo) %>"); is the issue with this code. I'm just not sure what I should replace in there to get it to work.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by using a partial